# Can you explain this dart json parsing code please?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, flutter, dart

So i have this code that works somehow, however i can't really explain why.
To get this code i used an automatic json to code application called [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) using as input a json that my company provides. The goal of the code is obtaining a Map containing polygons in this format : {(Random ID of polygon)} ==> [Lat,Lon]

```
class Poligoni {
  Map<String, List<String>> poligoni;
  Poligoni({
    this.poligoni,
  });
  factory Poligoni.fromRawJson(String str) {
    return Poligoni.fromJson(json.decode(str));
  }

  factory Poligoni.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Poligoni(
      poligoni: Map.from(json["Poligoni"]).map((k, v) {
        return MapEntry<String, List<String>>(
            k, List<String>.from(v.map((x) => x)));
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

---

So the code either accepts a raw json from the (.fromRawJson) function or a decoded one from (.fromJson)  function. No problems here. The part that confuses me is this one :

```
factory Poligoni.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Poligoni(
      poligoni: Map.from(json["Poligoni"]).map((k, v) {
        return MapEntry<String, List<String>>(
            k, List<String>.from(v.map((x) => x)));
      }),
    );
  }
```

The problems i have understanding this are(.fromJson function):

1. Why i return a Class? example: `return Poligoni(.....various code)`
2. The use of the redirecting constructor in not very clear in this case to me `poligoni:`
3. A lot of difficulty undestanding the function after `poligoni:` : i know that the function parses the json key 'Poligoni' and transform this in another map of type `<String>,List<String>`
   that contains for every key a list of points which form a polygon however i am not sure how, if you can write a step-by-step walk through it will be greatly appreciated or in alternative if you can reformat this code to make it clearer.

I tried looking through dart and flutter docs but i didn't unterstand most of it because of the nested functions that my code uses and a little bit of language barrier.

Any help is greatly aprreciated,
Best Regards.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why i return a Class? example: return Poligoni(.....various code)

Because you are using a factory constructor. A factory constructor is like a static method but your are required to return an instance of an object that are compatible with the class it is part of.

One advantage of this pattern is that when using a normal constructor, you are not allowed to set any final variables inside the constructor body but needs to set them as part of the initializing phase.

In you case, this is really not a problem since the variable `Map<String, List<String>> poligoni` is not `final` but it can still be a nice pattern.

Read more about factory constructors here:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors

> The use of the redirecting constructor in not very clear in this case to me poligoni:

See my previous answer.

> A lot of difficulty undestanding the function after poligoni: : i know that the function parses the json key 'Poligoni' and transform this in another map of type ,List that contains for every key a list of points which form a polygon however i am not sure how, if you can write a step-by-step walk through it will be greatly appreciated or in alternative if you can reformat this code to make it clearer.

```
factory Poligoni.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Poligoni(
      poligoni: Map.from(json["Poligoni"]).map((k, v) {
        return MapEntry<String, List<String>>(
            k, List<String>.from(v.map((x) => x)));
      }),
    );
  }
```

As previous stated we have defined a factory constructor which must return an object which are compatible with the class it is part of. In this case we therefore creates a new `Poligoni` object by calling the constructor of `Poligoni` which takes a named argument `poligoni`. This is why we have `poligoni:`.

We are setting the named argument `poligoni` to the value of the following statement:

```
Map.from(json["Poligoni"]).map((k, v) {
        return MapEntry<String, List<String>>(
            k, List<String>.from(v.map((x) => x)));
      })
```

I am not really sure why we are using `Map.from` but the purpose of this constructor is to create a new map based on the key-values from another map:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Map/Map.from.html

(personally, I would have used a typecast from `json["Poligoni"]` since this must be a `Map` instance)

We are then calling `.map` on this new `Map` to create another new `Map` but where each key-value pair is mapped to new key-value pairs by the following method:

```
(k, v) {
        return MapEntry<String, List<String>>(
            k, List<String>.from(v.map((x) => x)));
      }
```

We can see here we are keeping the original key `k` but are converting the value `v` with:

```
List<String>.from(v.map((x) => x))
```

My guess here is that `v` is `List<dynamic>` and we want to create a new list of the type `List<String>` by taking each element of List `v` and inserting it into a new List which has been defined as `List<String>` from the start.

The result of this is then used as value in our new `Map` which are then used as value for the `poligoni` argument.

In short, all of this operations are really used for making your code more type safe by converting `dynamic` types into statically determined types.